# webview transparent background §?

Tags: android

Can someone tell me why on my Samsung S3 `(v 4.1.1)` a webview has a transparent background and on the xperia U `(v 4.0.1)` it has a black background?

I use in the java code `'webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFFFF)'` and in the html 
`'<body style="background: transparent">'`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. All webviews on Xperia with Android 4.0.4 had opaque backgrounds, no matter what I did.

The solution was to disable hardware acceleration in all activities containing the bug ridden webviews.

Try to add this to the activity nodes in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

please use this, it's work for me

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Comment: On the S3 the background was and is transparent, but on the xperia was black and now it's white..

Answer (score 0):

It basically due to activity theme that different vendor use to style the view and change their look and feel.In this case you can extends webview and overide the setBackgroungColor(int color) method and do delcare your activity theme .you will always see difference in view like listview , progress bar check box , etc look different on different vendor devices.

Comment: ___I don't understand what I have to do.

Comment: when the device manufacture build os, he has the power to change code and add his own feature and look and feel to android OS , being Open Source , every vendor do so changes, ie HTC android phone have different theme vs Samsung Android Phones , So every vendor changes the generic style of view and background. What you can do is to extend the Webview and override the method and set your requisite background while drawing on canvas or use inbuilt methods.

Comment: How do you suppose to override native WebView's method? Do you mean one has to look in original source code of WebView and than what? Copy/paste just won't work. WebView extends AbsoluteLayout extends ViewGroup extends View. So do I need to get the original source code of View? Anyway using original source code wont help cuz it uses a bunch of private methods... So I just can't figure out what did you mean by Overriding in this case.

Comment: i was just saying to override the backgroung color , as it is a public method of Webview http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/WebView.java#WebView.setBackgroundColor%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

Also try webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);